# FXMLLoader error/warning when compiling javaFx program, although program runs fine

Tags: java, xml, javafx, fxml

When I compile my code I get the following message:

> javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
>   WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.131 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.72

Using IntelliJ 2017.1.3

This doesn't particularly matter as the program still seems to run fine, although it'd be nice to find out why it throws these error/warning

Comment: the version of scene builder its diffrent then jdk

Comment: Why not just update `SceneBuilder` and your `JDK` to most recent 8 version?

Comment: Is that the cause of the first line too? I will update them, i've been lazy as of late

Comment: You have to share your code segment also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess ,you created an FXML file using the Scene Builder tool.
When scene builder creates an FXML file ,the root has a an attribut :`xmlns` url which has the version of JDK.

**Example** :

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141"
```

And this warning happens because you load an FXML file using :

> xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.131"

But in your project you have a **JDK 8.0.72**,which means you should update your JDK to 8.0.131 or more that version.

Answer (score 1):

Tools creating fxmls like scenebuilder use a url for the namespace that contains the version number the tool works with, e.g.

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111"
```

When loading the fxml with an earlier version of JavaFX `FXMLLoader` issues a warning since it cannot guarantee all features of the newer version are already available.

This does not mean that you do in fact use unavailable features though which is why loading the fxml may succeed.